# Why can't I make this app a favorite, in the dock?

Tags: dock

I'm trying to make Waterfox (a Firefox fork) a favorite in the dock, but the option isn't there. I can't do it by dragging the icon to a different position, either. It worked fine until Waterfox updated recently. What gives?

[image]

Comment: @vanadium I disagree. For example, you could give general information about why this type of thing might happen. There can't be *that* many reasons why an application could be un-pinnable to the dock.

Comment: @vanadium Are there any possible reasons besides what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: @vanadium Yes, and I notice you were able to answer that question without knowing any further details than I posted here, and that you gave the same answer as me (which you said was wrong), other than the extra completeness of including the answer for Wayland as well.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the property `StartupWMClass` is not set in the corresponding `.desktop` file. Open the `.desktop` file you're trying to set as a favorite in a text editor, and add (in the `[Desktop Entry]` section) a line saying:

```
StartupWMClass=[see below]
```

To determine the correct value, launch the application (i.e. by double clicking the `.desktop` file). Now open a terminal and run `xprop WM_CLASS`. Click on the application. The terminal will print something like

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "waterfox"
```

Take the most "specific" seeming value and put it, without quotes, as the value of `StartupWMClass` in your `.desktop`, e.g. `StartupWMClass=waterfox`.

Comment: 1. This is not the reason why you cannot pin an application. 2. Your instructions may not work on a majority of standard Ubuntu 22.04 versions, where applications may be running on Wayland